# Crystal Reports Load Unload Dispose Events

Tags: asp.net, events, crystal-reports

I have an ASP.NET app that uses Crystal Reports through the CR Viewer.
The records shown are based on a session variable.
This part works fine.
However, I want to clear the session variable when they are done looking at the report.
So I tried to clear it in the page_unload event. To my surprise, that event fired while the report was loading up. The first page of the report still displays OK, but additional pages don't as the records it was based on is now empty.
Further testing showed that the page_unload event doesn't even fire when leaving the CR
I don't know why the page_unload fires after the page_load, but I figured I would try clearing my session variable in the page_disposed event. But that didn't fire either when I went to another page in my app.
I also tried the CrystalReportViewer1_Unload event, but that also fires on every page when loading.

So I'm looking for where I can clear the session variable when I know they are done looking at the report. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes up with an answer, that would still be great. But here's the work around I found.

The reason I wanted to clear the session variable was that it was storing a shopping cart, and after printing, I wanted the shopping cart empty in case they went shopping some more.
What I ended up doing was copying the session variable to another. I clear the fist one before printing use the second one for printing the records. It doesn't matter if the second one is cleared, or not, as it's not the real shopping cart.